# GREP - Searching for specific string going backwards

Tags: linux, bash, curl, grep

I would like to search file.txt with grep to locate a url ending with.  ".doc".  When it finds .doc, I want grep to go backwards and find "http://" at the begining of that string.

The output would be http://somesite.com/random-code-that-changes-daily/somefilename.doc

There is only 1 .doc url on this page, so multiple search results should not be an issue.

Please excuse, I am a novice.  I did locate the answer at one time but search for 1 hour and can no longer find.  I am willing to read and learn but I do not think I'm using the correct search terms for what I want to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression),

with the marker `^` you can indicate the start of the line you are looking for.

with the marker `$` you can indicate the end of the line you are looking for.

then, you can do something like

```
grep '^http:\\' \ '.doc$' file.txt
```

or

```
grep '^http://\|.doc$' file.txt
```

or not using regular expressions but just a matching pattern with wildcards as @choroba suggested:

```
grep 'http://.*\.doc' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also search for `http://` and print the line if it contains `.doc` somewhere after it:

```
grep 'http://.*\.doc' file.txt
```

If you want to only print the matching part, use the `-o` option (if your version of grep supports it).

Comment: I believe the backslash is not needed in this case.

Comment: @myradio: Why? A dot without a backslash matches any character, but we want to match a literal dot.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It would match any line ending with 'doc' and not '.doc'.